# In Star Trek (2009), was Chekov actually wrong for calling Spock "Commander" instead of "Captain"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, starfleet-rank

At some point after Spock becomes the captain but before Kirk does, he gives an order to Chekov who replies "Aye, Commander", then immediately corrects himself, saying "Ah! Captain, sorry, captain". Although Spock was in command and was made "the captain" by Pike, he still retained the rank of commander. Was Chekov wrong, in the sense that he could have been reprimanded as per Starfleet regulations, for calling Spock "Commander"?

Comment: Nog makes the same error

Comment: related: [Has any command structure officer ever given an order to a superior (in terms of rank) officer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149823/has-any-command-structure-officer-ever-given-an-order-to-a-superior-in-terms-of)

Comment: This question is unanswerable because the Starfleet rules and regulations around addressing officers, and consequences for addressing them incorrectly, do not exist.

Comment: also related: [Why was Sisko promoted to captain?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92131/why-was-sisko-promoted-to-captain)

Comment: To go sideways, whether any officer has ever given an order to a superior is a matter of historical fact. At the same time, "everyone (interested in things military) knows" there are protocols by which the man on the front line is entitled to say "General, I'm only a (What Rank) and I'm telling you, the situation requires (whatever action)"

The downside is career ending if not military prison and perhaps even a firing squad but that's a very different thing.

Comment: Sisko's rise to Captain is nonsense. Command of any station requires a certain rank, which might have leeway. In that sense, a Commander might be promoted Captain and keep the same job.

The idea that command of anything approaching the size or complexity, let alone the importance of DS9 could go to a mere Commander strikes me, for one, as ludicrous.

Make your own comparison between DS9 and any ship or shore station in any navy you know.

Is DS9 to be compared to a battleship? At very least, it is. Which navy can you see giving a battleship - even a cruiser - to a mere Commander?

Comment: DS9 was not particularly important at the time of Sisko's assignment, I think - it was a bit of enemy property with an unsavory reputation, gained diplomatically when Cardassia left Bajor, with value as a base for the few vessels expected to arrive from the Federation to far-off Bajor.  Sisko had a tiny staff, and few responsibilities other than to represent the Federation in the hopes that Bajor might join.  One DS9 became the gateway to an active wormhole to a different quadrant, things were very different - but by then, Sisko has special status: the Bajorans wouldn't accept anyone else.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Commander and Captain are (in current Naval practice) both ranks, but "Captain" is also a job.  One can be "the Captain" (commanding officer) without holding the rank of Captain (JFK was captain of a PT boat while holding the rank of LT).  However, for clarity and courtesy it is the practice to refer to the Commanding Officer as Captain regardless of rank.  Chekov had made an understandable mistake, but it is not likely to result in a reprimand (repeated misaddressal might lead to reprimand and charges).

Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_(naval)#Etiquette) (itself paraphrasing *The Naval Officer's Guide*):

> Any naval officer who commands a ship is addressed by naval custom as "captain" while aboard in command, regardless of their actual rank, even though technically an officer of below the rank of captain is more correctly titled the commanding officer, or C.O. Officers with the rank of captain travelling aboard a vessel they do not command should be addressed by their rank and name (e.g., "Captain Smith"), but they should not be referred to as "the captain" to avoid confusion with the vessel's captain

Per the [Manual for Courts-Martial](https://jsc.defense.gov/Portals/99/Documents/2019%20MCM%20(Final)%20(20190108).pdf?ver=2019-01-11-115724-610#page=329) (IV-21, paragraph 15; p. 329 of the PDF), the elements of Article 89 (Disrespect to a Superior Officer) are:

> 1. Disrespect toward superior commissioned
>    officer.
>
>    - (a) That the accused did or omitted certain acts or used certain language to or concerning a certain commissioned officer;
>    - (b) That such behavior or language was directed toward that officer;
>    - (c) That the officer toward whom the acts, omissions, or words were directed was the superior commissioned officer of the accused;
>    - (d) That the accused then knew that the commissioned officer toward whom the acts, omissions, or words were directed was the accused’s
>      superior commissioned officer; and
>    - (e) That, under the circumstances, the behavior or language was disrespectful to that commissioned officer.

Note, I am assuming that US Navy practices carry forward to Starfleet - but Roddenberry's rules for believability state that if you can't imagine a good current US Navy officer doing something, then it shouldn't happen in *Star Trek*.

Comment: OK, accepted. Thanks!

Comment: In the Caine Mutiny, Queeg captained the ship but  was a Lt. Cmdr.

Comment: This cannot be the answer because the Starfleet rules and regulations around addressing officers, and consequences for addressing them incorrectly, do not exist. It's a good speculative guess based on the fact that Star Trek was written by an American who presumably would have based these hypothetical rules on those of his own country's navy, but it is still only a guess.

Comment: @IanKemp Congratulations!  You've just invalidated the answers to 90% of the questions on here!

Comment: @IanKemp [ObXKCD](https://xkcd.com/2623/). In any case Starfleet has generally been viewed as modeled closely on the US Navy. There's probably even some documentation on this from Roddenberry, perhaps reported in something like "The Making of Star Trek".

Comment: @Barmar I was reading a thread about how Gene was actually in the Army Air Corps, so it's more like a mismash of AAC quirks and how the Navy might have been perceived by someone in a different service.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Possibly. But all the ranks mirror Navy ranks, as does much of the language, like "you have the conn", and traditions (burial at sea becomes casting the deceased into space). They even use the boatswain's call. The only one they seem to be missing is the use of "bells" for time of day.

Comment: The focus for me in this situation is that to refer to Spock as "Captain" shows the highest degree of respect for the _position_ that he holds. This is an acknowledgement that Spock is currently holding the highest rank on the vessel, even if his official rank is commander. It is understandable to refer to Spock out of habit by his commissioned rank, it takes time to adjust the mind to these things. The nervous correction from "Commander" to "Captain" is entirely in character and I'm glad they got it right.

Comment: I think there are also some cases where an admiral is in command of a ship and still called "captain" despite it being *lower* than their actual rank.

Comment: @Chris: I agree. It's realistic for people to make mistakes- and nice to see that shown

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate on [Valorum's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263574/in-star-trek-2009-was-chekov-actually-wrong-for-calling-spock-commander-ins#comment726412_263574), this has been addressed in the *DS9* episode "[Behind the Lines](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Behind_the_Lines_(episode))", where Commander Dax temporarily takes command of a ship.

> DAX: Are you two ever going to be finished?
>
> NOG: Just a few more minutes, Commander.
>
> O'BRIEN: That's Captain. It's an old naval tradition. Whoever's in command of a ship, regardless of rank, is referred to as Captain.

The fact that O'Brien calls it a tradition, and not a regulation, indicates that there probably would not be any punishment for Nog calling Dax 'Commander'.

A clip can be seen here:

Comment: @LogicDictates Thanks for the welcome, I edited the answer.